# Set and get global variable in php (ZendFramework)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using ZendFramework with PHP, and I want to set and get a variable as a global variable. I.E. I set it in the class of Zend Controller and access it any action in the class.

For example:

```
<?php

class SubscriptionController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    private $EMAIL = false;
    private $USERNAME = false;
```

First I am validating email addres with ajax call

```
    public function checkusernameAction()
    {
        $email = //query to find email;     
        if($email){
        $EMAIL = true;
        }else{
        $EMAIL = false;
        }
    }
```

then I want subscribe user on the basis of private variable again with ajax call

```
    public function subscribeAction
    {
      if($EMAIL == true)
       {
         //some stuff 
       }        
    }
```

I am  getting private var by $this->EMAIL, but not able to access it

Comment: Except for very limited cases, global variables should typically be avoided (too long to get into in a comment...).  Instead, maybe you should be referring back to the front controller to get the data.  (Though without knowing your exact situation I may be giving you bad advice.)

Comment: @Corbin...I modify and briefly describe my question. Please check it and help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) to use the variable throughout application.

You can set a variable like this

```
Zend_Registry::set('email', $EMAIL);
```

and later can get it like this

```
$email= Zend_Registry::get('email');
```

Comment: Thanx buddy....  this is the good option but I am facing a problem i.e I initialize the registry in init() with ::set('email' false) and again declaring it in other action that I am calling with ajax as ::set('email', true), and then checking it in third function as true or false and everytime i am getting false.  Is there any other option to do the same

Comment: I'm not sure if it will ease your life or not, but you could pass round a config object in the registry which just handles a subset of configuration options?

Comment: The link you mentioned about Zend_Registry is not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are making two distinct requests calling, respectively, `checkusernameAction()` and `subscribeAction()`. Since these are distinct requests, the email value you set in the controller during `checkusernameAction()` will be gone on the second request which calls `subscribeAction()`. It's the same controller *class*, but you are looking at two distinct *instances*, one in each request.

As I see it, you can either:

1. Pass the email address in each AJAX request, but this seems unlikely since you get the email address from the first call to `checkusernameAction()`.
2. Save the email in the session during the first `checkusernameAction()` call and then pick it up during the second `subscribeAction()` call.
3. Extract the "get email from username" code into a separate class or method and then call it in both places. After all, you don't want to get bitten by a "race condition" in which the state of the system changes between the two AJAX requests (maybe the user's email changes via some other process or via another set of requests that occur after the first AJAX request containing the call to `checkusernameAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used a function for set and get a value.

```
// Setter function
public function setConsumerKey($key)
{
    $this->_consumerKey = $key;
    return $this;
}

// Getter function

public function getConsumerKey()
{
    return $this->_consumerKey;
}
```

Comment: This is to access variable inside a class..But I want to access variable from different controllers and models.Like a catalyst object in catalyst framework